# Exporting elements from list to CSV in R

Tags: arrays, r, list, for-loop

I would like to export each element of class `array` from a `list` to a CSV file

example data:

```
mylist <- list(
    specimen1 = array(runif(3^2), dim=c(3,3)),
    specimen2 = array(runif(3^2), dim=c(3,3)),
    specimen3 = array(runif(3^2), dim=c(3,3))
)
```

I would also like to append _land to each csv file (e.g. specimen1_land.csv, specimen2_land.csv, specimen3_land.csv, etc.).

Comment: `2^3 == 8` and `dim= c(3, 3)` implies `3*3 == 9` elements: the last element of the array repeats the first.

Comment: @user3683803: Kindly consider to upvote or accept the answer when someone has answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Base R Solution):
Extract index wise data and write to the corresponding `.csv` file.

```
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
  write.csv(mylist[i], paste0(names(mylist)[i], "_land.csv"))
}
```

Comment: `sep = ".csv"` is wrong. It will become `"specimen1.csv_land"`, etc. Upvote, you beat me to it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I tried to run and it works perfectly :)  Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: You probably ran the first version of your code, when you had a different `sep`.

Comment: `paste0(names(mylist[i]),"_land.csv")`  and `paste0(names(mylist[i]),"_land",sep=".csv")` both work.

Comment: Output from second: `[1] "specimen1_land.csv"
[1] "specimen2_land.csv"
[1] "specimen3_land.csv"`

Comment: OK, you are right but that happened because `sep` is **not an argument** to `paste0` just to `paste`. So `paste0` will see `sep = ".csv"` as one of the values in its first argument, the dots argument `...`, which can be any number of arguments. It is a formal error to use `sep` and it is luck that it does not even throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

`MASS::write.matrix` is nice if you just want values, not row or column names. You can iterate over your list with `lapply`, or since you need to iterate over both objects and names, its multivariate version `Map`:

```
set.seed(47)
mylist <- list(
    specimen1 = array(runif(3^2), dim=c(3,3)),
    specimen2 = array(runif(3^2), dim=c(3,3)),
    specimen3 = array(runif(3^2), dim=c(3,3))
)

Map(
    function(obj, name) MASS::write.matrix(obj, name, sep = ","), 
    mylist,
    paste0(names(mylist), "_land.csv")
)
```

`purrr::imap` is a shortcut version of this that automatically iterates over both the elements `.x` and the names `.y`. `iwalk` is a version of the same function that doesn't produce any output (which is useless anyway, as you're calling the anonymous function for the side effects).

```
library(purrr)

mylist %>% iwalk(~MASS::write.matrix(.x, paste0(.y, "_land.csv"), sep = ","))
```

Both do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `mapply`

```
mapply(write.csv, x=mylist, file=sprintf("specimen%i_land.csv", 1:3))
# edit: alistaire's answer uses Map, which is the same as mapply
# so the only unique bit here is sprintf
```

or `sapply`:

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) write.csv(mylist[[i]], sprintf("specimen%i_land.csv",i)))
```